# Trouble parsing Brainfuck brackets in Python

Tags: python, brainfuck

I'm making a compiler for Brainfuck in Python as practice w/ the language. Most of the symbols haven't been too much of a challenge but I am absolutely stumped on `[` and `]`.

Here is what I have so far

```
global cells
global pointer
cells = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pointer = 0

#bfcode = list(input())
bfcode = list("+x+++,[>++++<-]>.")
for i in range(len(bfcode)):
    if(bfcode[i] == "."):
        print(cells[pointer])
    elif(bfcode[i] == ","):
        charin = list(input("Write one character: "))[0]
        cells[pointer] = ord(charin)
    elif(bfcode[i] == "+"):
        cells[pointer] += 1
    elif(bfcode[i] == "-"):
        cells[pointer] -= 1
    elif(bfcode[i] == ">"):
        pointer += 1
    elif(bfcode[i] == "<"):
        pointer -= 1
    elif(bfcode[i] == "["):
        print("PLACEHOLDER")
    elif(bfcode[i] == "]"):
        print("PLACEHOLDER")
    else:
        print("Non-brainfuck character detected")
    print(cells)
```

So, as a Python newbie, my first instinct is to somehow go backwards in the for-loop but from what I can tell that isn't possible in Python. I've googled solutions to going backwards in a loop but all of them are way beyond my comprehension at the moment...

Is there an easy way to go backwards in a for-loop that I somehow missed? Or maybe is there an easier way to do it all together?

<sup>Other tips and suggestions for my code are appreciated too, since I'm still learning :)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
elif ins == '[':
                # only does stuff if memory isnt zero
                if mem[ptr] == 0:
                    # initialistation
                    count = 0
                    ic += 1
                    # keeps going until the end of the program
                    while ic <= len(self.prg):
                        # sets instruction
                        ins = self.prg[ic]
                        # if has found the matching bracket, it ends
                        if ins == ']' and count == 0:
                            break
                        # deals with nested loops
                        elif ins == '[':
                            count += 1
                        elif ins == ']':
                            count -= 1
                        # moves forward one place in the program
                        ic += 1
            # its an algorithim, dont ask
            elif ins == ']':
                # only does stuff if memory is zero
                if mem[ptr] != 0:
                    # initialistation
                    count = 0
                    ic -= 1
                    # keeps going until the end of the program
                    while ic >= 0:
                        # sets instruction
                        ins = self.prg[ic]
                        # if has found the matching bracket, it ends
                        if ins == '[' and count == 0:
                            break
                        # deals with nested loops
                        elif ins == ']':
                            count += 1
                        elif ins == '[':
                            count -= 1
                        # moves backward one place in the program
                        ic -= 1
```

It may not use the same structure as you, but should give you a few ideas.

In short, you loop through the code, adding one when finding a open bracket, and subtracting one when you find a close bracket, to find the matching close bracket.